# Which preposition fits better in my own example?

Tags: word-choice

I am going to make up my own example below.

(ex) I am very sleepy today because I did not have enough sleep **"over"** or **"for"** or **"during"** the last three nights.

Which preposition works better in my example above?

Comment: for the last three nights or over the last three nights. Not during. During the day, I often fall asleep.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you could omit all of your suggestions in that example, eg.  "I am very sleepy today because I did not have enough sleep the last three nights".

Personally I would also change 'have' to 'get', as it makes more sense, eg. "I am very sleepy today because I did not get enough sleep the last three nights"